# String files for python web

Tags: python, string, flask

Hellos guys, I'm making a web system in python using flask. I'm going to need a string file to translate the system to different languages(Like on Android), but I have no idea how to do it on python. Does anyone knows how I could do it?

Comment: what is a string file?

Comment: I meant a file with strings for translation like you can find on android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [Flask-Babel](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/). Python uses the GNU gettext system for translation, via the [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/gettext.html) module. [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) is a package that provides tools for making gettext translation files (among other things), and Flask-Babel is for using Babel in Flask applications.

Comment: Thanks man, that was exactly what I needed.